# Can I make IDLE shell show me the description of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I'm new to Python and I'm using IDLE. What command do I use, so Python shell (after pressed f5) shows me the description (the thing I wrote in """ """ after the function name)
and / or shows the descriptions of other function!?

If it differs in 2.7 and 3.3 I'd appreciate if you mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "thing" is called [Docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and can easily be accessed by their dictionary attribute [__ doc __](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node100.html)

```
>>> def testfunc():
...     """ My Docstrings """
...     print "test"
... 

>>> testfunc.__doc__
' My Docstrings '
```

Answer (score 2):

What you write in the """ """ is called docstring.

When you want to print this you can use the `__doc__` attribute of the type. (Type means class, method or module).

You can check the available attribute with the Built-in function [dir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score 1):

You use:

```
help(your_function_name)
```

Like I did here:

```
>>> def sayhello():
    """This says hello to you"""
    print "Hello there!"

>>> help(sayhello)
Help on function sayhello in module __main__:

sayhello()
    This says hello to you
```

Edit:
You must have imported your own module first.

Comment: if he needs a string, this won't work, since it prints to std.out and will require the use of the render_doc method from pydoc module

Comment: @ Samuele: I know but he asked what command he should use to show him the description.

Comment: i know :) i was just adding for clarification to him :)

Comment: No problem in that :). New guys must learn how much they can after all.

Answer (score 0):

use help() function

example:

> > > help(print)
> > >       Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

```
Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```